# iPad Internet Issues

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

My iPad will not connect to the Internet, even though it says that it is connected with full strength. Everything else in the house is connected.

There's one complication, my iPad's on/off button is broken (I dropped my iPad), so I can't turn it on or off.

My iPad stopped being able to connect to the Internet last night. YouTube videos don't play, Safari pages don't load. My son was watching a video on YouTube, and all of a sudden the video stopped. A message popped up saying I wasn't connected to the Internet.

Not sure what to do however any help appreciated.

Comment: Try performing basic troubleshooting steps: turn your iPad off and on again and cycle wifi off and on again. Yes, I know your power button is broken, but use these instructions to turn on Assistive Touch and restart your iPad without needing the power button: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5703078?tstart=0    Then comment back `@JohnRamos` with what happens. I have one other troubleshooting step you could try if those don't work.

Comment: Please try power cycling your iPad as per my earlier comment.

Comment: Try static wifi connection with ip 192.168.1.128?

Comment: You could also try going into Airplane mode for a few minutes, then see if things work better upon re-associating with the router.